# How to make an hyperellipsoid touch a hyperplane

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, ellipsoids

Let's say we have an hyperellipsoid $\mathcal{E}$ defined by the symmetric, positive definite matrix $P$, i.e.,

$$\mathcal{E} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x^\top P x = c \}$$

where $c>0$. I would like to find the biggest $c$ possible to make $\mathcal{E}$ touch the hyperplane $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid a^\top x = b\}$. According to a German book I read, this problem can be solved using Lagrange multipliers. Stated as an optimization problem, this should read
$$
\begin{align}
&\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} x^\top P x = c \\
&\mathrm{s.t.} \: a^\top x = b
\end{align}
$$
The corresponding Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L} = x^\top P x - \lambda (a^\top x-b)$ with $\lambda$ being the Lagrange multiplier. The necessary condition for optimality leads to the linear system
$$ 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
-a & 2P \\
0 & a^\top 
\end{bmatrix}}_{ =A}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda \\
x
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
b
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
and I have no idea how to invert $A$. Am I even on the right track? Any hint/help would be greatly appreciated.

**Remark**: The aforementioned book states that the solution is $c = {b^2 \over a^\top P^{-1} a }$ if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

No need to maximize. We know that at tangency

$$
2 P x = \mu a\Rightarrow 2x^{T}P x = \mu x^T a\Rightarrow 2c=\mu b\Rightarrow \mu = 2\frac cb
$$

substituting the last result into $2 P x = \mu a$ we get $x = \frac cb P^{-1}a$ and finally substituting this result into $a^T x = b$ we obtain the solution

$$
c=\frac{b^2}{a^T P^{-1}a}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's much easier than I initially thought. Should I delete the question (and the following solution)?

By switching $\lambda$ and $x$ in the above linear system, we can use the ansatz
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2P & -a \\
a^\top & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
D & e \\
f^T & g 
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $e,f \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $g \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
Solving this provides us with $e=\frac{P^{-1}a}{a^\top P^{-1} a}$ and $x=b e$. Inserting the so found $x$ into $c=x^\top P x$ yields the desired result.